# How do I draw a B-Tree that looks like following

Tags: tikz-styles

I'm trying to draw a B-Tree with vertical connections to leaves; also, the values inside a node are separated by space only.

See the picture below.

[image: B-Tree]

So far, I have following.

```
\documentclass[titlepage,11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz} %draw trees etc
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, shapes.misc, calc}
%\usepackage{tikz-qtree}


\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{bplus}=[rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split ignore empty parts, rounded corners, inner sep=7pt, draw, fill=white]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[bplus]
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=10mm]
%\tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=20mm]

    \node {19 \nodepart{two} 21}
        child {node{ o }}
        child {node{ o }}
        child {node{ o }}
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

There are 3 points I can't figure out.

1. How do I remove the vertical line separator?
2. How do I produce an empty node as a circle?
3. How do I make the connection vertical?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JouleV added code so far

Comment: Please include the entire MWE, including `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}...\end{document}`.

Comment: @whatisit see last version (should now be a full tex file)

Answer (score 3):

without `trees`:

```
\documentclass[titlepage,11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz} %draw trees etc
\usetikzlibrary{fit, matrix, positioning, calc}
%\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\tikzset{
    bplus/.style={rounded corners, inner sep=7pt, draw, fill=white}
}   

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={draw, circle, minimum size=5mm}, column sep=2mm,] (a)
    {&&&[5mm]&&[5mm]&&\\};
    \node[fit=(a-1-1) (a-1-3), rounded corners, draw, above=1cm of a-1-2, label={[font=\bfseries]center:{1\ \ 3}}] (b1) {};
    \node[fit=(a-1-6) (a-1-8), rounded corners, draw, above=1cm of a-1-7, label={[font=\bfseries]center:{12\ \ 15}}] (b3) {};
    \path (b1)--(b3) node[midway, fit=(a-1-4) (a-1-5), rounded corners, draw, label={[font=\bfseries]center:{6}}] (b2) {};
    \node[fit=(a-1-6) (a-1-8), rounded corners, draw, above=1cm of b2, label={[font=\bfseries]center:{5\ \ 7}}] (c1) {};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,3}{
        \draw (a-1-\i)--(a-1-\i|-b1.south);
        \draw (b\i)--(c1);}
    \foreach \i in {4,...,5}
        \draw (a-1-\i)--(a-1-\i|-b2.south);
    \foreach \i in {6,...,8}
        \draw (a-1-\i)--(a-1-\i|-b3.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My compliments. Very nice.

Comment: well, now I only need to make like 20 of those... I really did hope something along the lines of "rectangle split horizontal" etc would be possible (or qtree).